# setup.py to install dependencies through pip instead of compiling

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

With `python setup.py install` the script downloads and compiles the packages found in `install_requires` if those are not installed already. Is there a way to have them installed using `pip` instead? I would like to somehow change the `setup.py` file so that this happens automatically without the user having to type `pip install package_dependency`.
Some packages can take quite some time to compile (e.g., scipy), but installing them through pip downloads the binary so it's quite fast.

Comment: `pip install something`?

Comment: I mean, to be done automatically as specified in the `setup.py` file.